# Looking for a fantasy book about an angry god, a sentient robot, a ghost child and man in a black suit

Tags: story-identification, robots

There's two factions in the book "black" and "white". The white believe they can earn the god's approval, the black wish to kill him so he doesn't destroy them. He has caused apocalyptic events by launching massive metal orbs from just outside of orbit where he spends his time. There's a robot that's become self-aware and wishes to aid the main character, who's a blacksuit. The female character has a dead child that follows her around. The book culminates in a tournament where the Blacksuits and Whitesuits fight.

Answer (score 1):

*Jeroun* by Zachary Jernigan. The first book is called [*No Return*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1548470).

Quoting from the description on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15817069-no-return):

> Under the looming judgment of Adrash and his ultimate weapon—**a string of spinning spheres beside the moon** known as The Needle—warring **factions of white and black suits** prove their opposition to the orbiting god with **the great fighting tournament of Danoor**, on the far side of Jeroun’s only inhabitable continent.
>
> From the Thirteenth Order of **Black Suits comes Vedas, a young master** of martial arts, laden with guilt over the death of one of his students. Traveling with him are Churls, **a warrior woman and mercenary haunted by the ghost of her daughter**, and **Berun, a constructed man** made of modular spheres possessed by the foul spirit of his creator. Together they must brave their own demons, as well as thieves, mages, beasts, dearth, and hardship on the perilous road to Danoor, and the bloody sectarian battle that is sure to follow.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please [edit] your answer to explain why you think this is the answer.